# wikitude tutorial for ios and objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am implementing wikitude SDK for my iOS project. Now in the tutorial its showing step by step and i am following that. there is an option for adding ARchitectWorld. I am not getting what to add in that folder option. Shall I have to take the .js .css and .html file from the example they have shown. i am getting bit confused. Now I have also added the code. But not getting anything fruitful. What my question is what code should I have to add to get the ARworld work. I am tetsing on my iPOD 5th generation. Its showing me a message and the screen is blank.

The message is `This device is not capable of running ARchitect Worlds. Requirements are: iOS 6 or higher, iPhone 3GS or higher, iPad 2 or higher. Note: iPod Touch 4th and 5th generation are only supported in WTAugmentedRealityMode_IR.`

My code is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSLog(@"here it comes");
    if ( [WTArchitectView isDeviceSupportedForAugmentedRealityMode:WTAugmentedRealityMode_Both] ) { // 1

        NSLog(@"not entering");
        self.architectView = [[WTArchitectView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds motionManager:nil augmentedRealityMode:WTAugmentedRealityMode_Both];

       // [self.architectView setLicenseKey:@"MY-LICENSE-KEY"]; // 2
        [self.architectView setLicenseKey:nil];

        NSURL *architectWorldUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
        [self.architectView loadArchitectWorldFromUrl:architectWorldUrl];

        [self.view addSubview:self.architectView]; // 3
    }

    else {



        NSLog(@"This device is not capable of running ARchitect Worlds. Requirements are: iOS 6 or higher, iPhone 3GS or higher, iPad 2 or higher. Note: iPod Touch 4th and 5th generation are only supported in WTAugmentedRealityMode_IR.");
    }

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    [self.architectView start];
    if ( [self.architectView isRunning] ) {

       NSLog(@"ARchitect is running with version: %@", [WTArchitectView versionNumber]);
    }else {
       NSLog(@"WTARchitectView wasn't able to start. Please check e.g. the -ObjC linker flag in your project settings.");
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)startAR
{
    if([self.architectView isRunning])
    {

        NSLog(@"architect view is working");
        [self.architectView start];
    }
    else{
         NSLog(@"architect view is NOT working");
    }
}
-(void)stopAR
{
    if([self.architectView isRunning])
    {
        [self.architectView stop];
    }


}
```

Any help is needed. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. When I ran the project in iPhone, it worked fine. Don't try with iPods.

And you also need to check whether all the steps in [this link](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/ios/setupguideios.html) was done correctly.

Especially configuriing Build Settings in **both** Projests and Targets tab,

> The Wikitude SDK requires that the -ObjC linker flag is set. Linker
>   flags can be adjusted in the projects Build Settings tab. Search for
>   Other Linker Flags and add a new entry if it does not already exist.

[image]